# How to implement Ajax in Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I have a basic but functional search mechanism in my Symfony2 project.This will query and display back to the user the data using Doctrine2 LIKE expression.But I want to make more 'dynamic' and more 'user-friendly' by adding Ajax functionality.I added some Ajax code in my controller, but I don't know how to make it work.The image loader is just 'spinning' without displaying the results.

```
//controller

public function searcAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $this->getRequest()->get('query');

    if(!$query) {
        if(!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('voters_list'));
        } else {
            return new Response('No results.');
        }
    }

    $city = $em->getRepository('DuterteBundle:City')->findCity($query);

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if('*' == $query || !$city || $query == '') {
            return new Response('No results.');
        }
        //display a another page
        return $this->render('DuterteBundle:City:list1.html.twig', array('city' => $city));
    }

    return $this->render('DuterteBundle:City:search.html.twig', array('city' => $city));
}
```

// routing

```
search:
path: /search
defaults: { _controller:DuterteBundle:City:Searc }
requirements:


//search.html.twig

{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<div id="city">
    {% include 'DuterteBundle:City:list1.html.twig' with {'city': city} %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

//list1.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h4>City/Municipality/Town and Its Corresponding Numbers of Voters</h4>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Votes</th>
            <th>Percent</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for city in city %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ city }}</td>
            <td>{{ number_votes_city(city.id) }}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

My search form is embedded in navbar in the main layout.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" id="search">
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action ="{{ path('search')}}" method ="post">
 <div class="input-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search city/town" name="query" value="{{ app.request.get('query') }}" id="search_keywords">
 <div class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  <img id="loader" src="{{ asset('bundles/duterte/images/loader.gif') }}" style="vertical-align: middle; display: none" />
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

```
//repository

public function findCity($city)
{

    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.name LIKE :name_city')
        ->setParameter('name_city', '%'.$city.'%')
        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

and finally the js file

```
 $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('.search input[type="submit"]').hide();
                $('#search_keywords').keyup(function(key)
                {
                    if(this.value.length >= 3 || this.value == '') {
                        $('#loader').show();
                        $('#city').load(
                            $(this).parent('form').attr('action'),
                            { query: this.value ? this.value + '*' : this.value },
                            function() {
                                $('#loader').hide();
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });
            });
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have any error in the log files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same functionality, but a different approach. Listen to the keyup event on the search box
and then make ajax calls to a controller that returns the list of matched results as json. Check the response and
based on the status of the response, hide the existing listing and replace its contents with the markup returned in the
json response for the AJAX call.

Here, the example is for search in user listing.

1. Table markup on the twig file

   ```
   <div id="user-list-div">
    <table class="records_list" id="user-list">
   <thead>
   <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Username</th>
       <th>Password</th>
       <th>Salt</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Isactive</th>
       <th>Createdat</th>
       <th>Updatedat</th>
       <th>Isbillableuser</th>
       <th>Isdeleted</th>
       <th>Actions</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id = "user-table">
   {% for entity in entities %}
       <tr>
           <td><a href="{{ path('admin_user_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
           <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ entity.username }}</td>
           <td>{{ entity.password }}</td>
           <td>{{ entity.salt }}</td>
           <td>{{ entity.email }}</td>
           <td>{{ entity.isActive }}</td>
           <td>{% if entity.createdAt %}{{ entity.createdAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif %}</td>
           <td>{% if entity.updatedAt %}{{ entity.updatedAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif %}</td>
           <td>{{ entity.isBillableUser }}</td>
           <td>{{ entity.isDeleted }}</td>
           <td>
               <ul>
                   <li>
                       <a href="{{ path('admin_user_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="{{ path('admin_user_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </td>
       </tr>
   {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
   ```
2. Search form markup

   ```
   <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-field">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```
3. javascript part

   ```
   <script>
       $(function(){
           console.log('desperate for');

           var searchField = $('#search-field');
           var userTable = $('#user-table');
           var userListDiv = $('#user-list-div');

           searchField.keyup(function(evt){
               console.log($(this).val());

               $.ajax({
                   url: '{{ path('admin_user_search') }}',
                   method: "POST",
                   data: "id=" + $(this).val() ,
                   dataType: 'html',
                   success: function(result, request) {

                     var parsedData =JSON.parse(result);
                       console.log(parsedData);
                       if(parsedData.status ==='success'){
                           console.log('hete');
                           userListDiv.empty();
                           userListDiv.html(parsedData.data);
                       }else{
                           //handle no result case
                       }
                   }
               });
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```
4. ajax_template.html.twig file

The same table markup as given above

5. controller action

   public function searchuserAction(){
           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $request = $this->get('request');

   ```
       $searchParameter = $request->request->get('id');

       //call repository function

       $entities = $em->getRepository('LBCoreBundle:User')->findUsersForname($searchParameter);
       $status = 'error';
       $html = '';
       if($entities){
           $data = $this->render('LBCoreBundle:User:ajax_template.html.twig', array(
               'entities' => $entities,
           ));
           $status = 'success';
           $html = $data->getContent();
       }


       $jsonArray = array(
           'status' => $status,
           'data' => $html,
       );

       $response = new Response(json_encode($jsonArray));
       $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

       return $response;
   }
   ```
6. Respository function

   ```
   public function findUsersForname($name){
       $em = $this->getEntityManager();

       $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e FROM LBCoreBundle:User e
                WHERE e.username LIKE '%$name%'");

       $entities = $query->getResult();
       return $entities;

   }
   ```

Comment: @Pravesh this approach does not return my form as well as the table.Instead it return all markup and data in json format

Comment: The client side javascript is supposed to insert the html markup returned by the Ajax call into your listing page.